# F5 config to send requests via proxy server

Tags: f5, big-ip

We are using F5 v12.1.3 and what seems like a simple requirement is causing us a little trouble.

We would like to allow for a request that is sent to an F5 virtual server vip to be routed via a proxy. 
The equivalent curl request would be something fairly simple like

`curl --proxy [IP] -LIK [URL]`

which works from the F5 machine itself. We've looked at a combination of tunnels / [dns resolvers](https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/forward-explicit-ssl-proxy-server-48672) / iRules but are hopeful that we have just missed a simple configuration option somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.
Note; this question does not relate to SSL - that will come next - first we just want to create our route.

Thanks

[Update]
When we ssh to the machine that the F5 software is deployed on and try the curl request it works, this proves to us that the connectivity is there between the F5 machine and the endpoint we are trying to reach, as well as the proxy server. Just creating a virtual server pointing to the URL endpoint doesn't work as it needs to be proxied.

[Update 2]

We are trying to achieve the following

```
Generic VM hosting some app
          |
          |
          v
Call F5 VIP (say 1.1.1.1:8123)
          |
          |
          v
F5 forwards any traffic from 1.1.1.1:8123 to our designated endpoint, say https://endpoint.com but VIA a proxy server
```

I hope that helps...

Comment: _"which works from the F5 machine itself."_ So? Does it **not** work somewhere else? Where and why not? What was the error?

Comment: Thanks for your comment; when we ssh to the machine that the F5 software is deployed on and try the curl request it works, this proves to us that the connectivity is there between the F5 machine and the endpoint we are trying to reach, as well as the proxy server. Just creating a virtual server pointing to the URL endpoint doesn't work as it needs to be proxied.

Comment: what is the proxy when running from the BIG-IP? Still not entirely sure what your goal is.

Comment: It turns out what we need is the following feature; https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_apm/manuals/product/apm-secure-web-gateway-13-0-0/8.html which was only released in v13. I'll update the question with a better description.